# Gsettings don't use memory store

Tags: debian, gsettings

Gsettings seems to have switched to storing configuration in memory on my system, which means (among other things) that a lot of settings are forgotten when I reboot.

How do I tell it to not use the memory store?

Comment: can you explain a little more about this? When you reboot are you getting the schemas listed using `gsettings list-schemas`? Give us some more explanation!!!

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a full list.

Comment: then what's the problem? What do you mean by the settings are forgotten? The key value pairs in the `gsettings` are gone. What else? Elaborate!!!!!!!!!!!!